# attributes construct error in Entity, line: 14

Tags: xslt

I have this xslt :

```
<xsl:param name="total_articles" select="3" />
<xsl:param name="articles_per_page" select="3" />

<xsl:apply-templates select="dagboek/entry[position &gt; $offset][position &lt; $articles_per_page+$offset]" >
   <xsl:with-param name="total_pages" tunnel="yes">
  <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="$value="2005-09" and $page="1">8</xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>floor(number($total_articles)-1) div $articles_per_page +1</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:with-param>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

But now I get this error.

How can I calculate the outcome of the calculation and put it into the param total_pages.

Roelof

**Edit 1:** WHat I try to achieve is that if it's not 2005-09 and page is not 1 then the totalpages is calculated out of `total_articles` and `articles_per_page`. The outcome has to be put into the param pages.

Comment: *"this error"* - I don't see it?

Comment: "Line 14" isn't helpful as you haven't provided the code from its beginning.

Comment: Are you sure that your XSLT processor implements XSLT 2.0? Tunnel parameters are a feature of XSLT 2.0 but not of XSLT 1.0.

Comment: Chips, I have to work with xslt 1.0. So I have to alter my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <xsl:when test="$value="2005-09" and $page="1">8</xsl:when>
> ```

This isn't even well-formed XML document. The problem is with the nested quotes.

**Probably you meant**:

```
<xsl:when test="$value='2005-09' and $page='1' ">8</xsl:when>
```

**Another possible problem**: Tunnel parameters are only available in XSLT 2.0. You seem to be using XSLT 1.0

**Update**:

The OP in a comment has modified/clarified his initial question:

> WHat I try to achieve is that if it's not 2005-09 and page is not 1
>   then the totalpages is calculated out of total_articles and
>   articles_per_page. The outcome has to be put into the param pages.

This can simply be expressed as:

```
   <xsl:with-param name="total_pages" select=
    "8*($value='2005-09' and $page='1')
    +
     (floor(number($total_articles)-1) div $articles_per_page +1)
    *
     not($value='2005-09' and $page='1')
    "/>
```

**Explanation**:

We are using the fact that in XPath 1.0 by definition  `number($someBoolean)` is `1` if `$someBoolean` is `true()` and is `0` if `$someBoolean` is `false()`.

Therefore the pseudocode:

```
 if($vCond)
  then $vNum1
  else $vNum2
```

can be expressed with a single XPath expression:

```
$vNum1*$vCond + $vNum2*not($vCond )
```

whenever a boolean is an argument to an arithmetic operator, it is automatically converted to a number.

So, here's what happens at run-time:

1. Suppose `$vCond` is `true()`, therefore `not($vCond)` is `false()`.
2. Because `$vCond` and  `not($vCond)` are arguments to the `*` operator, they are converted to numbers, respectively `1` and `0`:

...

```
$vNum1*1 + $vNum2*0
```

1. This is equivalent to:

...

```
$vNum1*1
```

**Note**:

The above equivalence rule can be further generalized to N *mutually exclusive* conditions `$vCond1`, `$vCond2`, ..., `$vCondN`,  and corresponding N values: `$val1`, `$val2`, ..., `$valN`:

```
$val1*$vCond1 + $val2*$vCond2 + ... + $valN*$vCondN
```

is equal to `$valK` (`k` in `{1,..., N}`) exactly when `$vCondK` is `true()`

Comment: @RoelofWobben: NP, I modified my answer (see the update at the very end) to solve your latest-comment-modified question :)

Comment: Thanks , and if I want to do this `<xsl:when test=" month=2005-02 and page=1>8 </xsl:when> < when test="2005-03 and page=1> 8</when> <otherwise> 9</otherwise>`

Comment: sorry, I forget the choose but what I mean is that there are several if then and if no if then is valid then a standard value passed like the choose , when otherwise tags.

Comment: Can this be a solution : http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N8090.html#d10874e1009

Comment: @RoelofWobben: I showed you a correct solution several times in a row. Such comments-dialogue isn't the best way of communication. Better, ask a new question. Also, your current question and add-on comments have been answered a number of times -- please, consider accepting an answer. In general, your questions are about simple logic and set arithmetic -- it would probably be a good idea to read about and understand this topic.

Comment: @RoelofWobben: And in your case you don't need at all `xsl:choose` or anything else inside the body of the variable. All arithmetics can be specified in the `select` attribute of `xsl:variable` -- the body can be empty. This is explained at the end of my answer.

Comment: Oke, last querstion. If the last value is needed when all the others are not true then I can use $val1*$vCond1 + $val2*$vCond2 + ... + $valN*not(Cond1 and not(cond2) and so on.

Comment: @RoelofWobben: Yes, more compact is: ... `not($Cond1 or $Cond2 ... or $CondN)`

Answer (score 0):

You have a badly formed attribute:

```
<xsl:when test="$value="2005-09" and $page="1">8</xsl:when>
```

It should probably look like:

```
<xsl:when test="$value='2005-09' and $page='1'">8</xsl:when>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it this line?

```
<xsl:when test="$value="2005-09" and $page="1">8</xsl:when>
```

You're nesting double quotes - that's not going to work. Use a combination of single and double quotes :

```
<xsl:when test='$value="2005-09" and $page=1'>8</xsl:when>
```